# Using cc2530 radio with contiki

Tags: contiki, lpc, radio-transmission

I am trying to build a port for Contiki on my lpc1347 board. I have set up the mcu libraries and makefiles, all that is left is to add the radio support.
My goal is to use a cc2530 radio that I have, the problem is i do not know much about this. I see that that there is already a port for c2530, but i want to use cc2530 as a radio, so is it necessary to port Contiki in that too? How should i go about adding my lpc1347 board support for cc2530's contiki files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CC2530 is a SoC device with a 8051 MCU. You'll have to program this 8051 processor in order to use the radio. If Contiki is already running on your lpc1347 it is not necessary to port it on the cc2530 too, but you'll have to communicate with this latter in someway (uart, spi, ...) in order to send/receive radio packet and turn on/off the radio.

I suggest you to write a file i.e `cpu/lpc1347/dev/cc2530-rf.c` and implement a new radio driver using one of the communication interface. Implement each functions require by the structure `struct radio_driver` which is found in `core/dev/radio.h` and set the `NETSTACK_CONF_RADIO` variable to this new radio driver.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Can you please also suggest me where i can read about programming a radio also..

Comment: The only place is to look in the datasheet of the CC2530. The access to the required radio registers is already implemented in `contiki/cpu/cc253x/dev/cc2530-rf.c` so get inspired from there.